# Assigning Facebook app username

Tags: facebook

I have a question that's concerning Facebook usernames.

I claimed the username for my App's Facebook fan page and I need to know how to assign the same username for the Facebook App?

Edit:
I originally searched forum.developers.facebook.net for the answer.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `username`? Are you maybe referring to the "vanity URL" that you are allowed to choose once you have 25 likes on the page?

Answer (score 0):

To assign your facebook app a "username" you will need to enter it into the "App Namespace" field of Basic Info section on `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/summary`. Scroll to the bottom and click save.